# C++ - DirectX11 covers direct2d texture

Tags: directx

this is my first post on this forum. About 3 months ago i start to learn DirectX 11 (with C++). I am trying to write my own engine based on directx 11 and i've seen small disadvantage when i am drawing Direct2D content on top of DirectX11 content. I understand why it is happening but i don't know how to fix it. I think the problem is with matrix transformation of quad to which i draw direct 2d content. I learn from www.braynzarsoft.net. The lesson: [Tutorial 14: DirectX 11 Simple Font](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11FONT)

i.stack.imgur.com/Ok4Nl.png

i.stack.imgur.com/mR7UH.png

The matrix transformation and the way i am drawing quad on "top" of directx 11 content:

```
XMFLOAT4X4 WVP;
xmset(WVP, XMMatrixIdentity());
xmset(device->m_PerObject.m_wvp, XMMatrixTranspose(XMFloat4X4ToXMMatrix(WVP)));
xmset(device->m_PerObject.m_world, XMMatrixTranspose(XMFloat4X4ToXMMatrix(WVP)));
device->getDeviceContext()->UpdateSubresource(device->getPerObjectInfo()->getBuffer(), 0, NULL, &(device->m_PerObject), 0, 0);
device->getDeviceContext()->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, device->getPerObjectInfo()->getBufferPtr() );
device->getDeviceContext()->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_d2dTexture);
device->getDeviceContext()->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampState);
device->getDeviceContext()->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);
```

I wrote function "xmset" to assign second parameter to first parameter (using XMFLOAT4X4 or XMFLOAT3 to prevent crashes due tu 16 alignment).
Like the tutorial says i've assigned XMMatrixIdentity() to WVP (World View Projection) and then passed it to constant buffer. How can i draw ALWAYS on top of DirectX 11 content?

Comment: Note that with this usage pattern for DirectXMath, you should probably just use SimpleMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which provides implicit conversion operators for ``XMFLOAT4<->XMVECTOR`` and ``XMFLOAT4X4<->XMMATRIX``.

Comment: The issue is not likely to be the transformation matrix, but the depth order or depth state. Note that tutorial is assuming you are using a DirectX 11.0 system. You don't need to use DXGI surface sharing and multiple devices to render Direct2D on a Direct3D 11 device when using a system with the DirectX 11.1 runtime installed.

Comment: I am writing engine in DirectX 11.0 So what can i google to find answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Like Chuck Walbourn said the problem was in depth state. I had to create two depth states - for direct2d (DepthEnable = false) and direct3d (DepthEnable = true). If someone have the same problem all you need is two ID3D11DepthStencilState. Thanks alot!